# JSDoc adding real code in documentation

Tags: javascript, documentation, jsdoc

Do you know if there is some sort of `<code />` tag in JSDoc? I need to add pieces of code in my documentation like this:

```
/**
 * This function does something see example below:
 *
 * var x = foo("test"); //it will show "test" message
 *
 * @param {string} str: string argument that will be shown in message
 */
function foo(str)
{
   alert(str);
}
```

I need the code in the comments to be displayed by JSDoc as code (if not syntax highlighted, at least like pre-formatted or something with grey background).

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use

```
<pre><code>

....

</code></pre>
```

This is whats used in many official docs, and will for instance receive syntax hightlighting with some tools

Comment: That seems odd. It is invalid HTML. Pre elements may contain code elements, but not the other way around.

Comment: @David, It might be that I remembered incorrectly about the order of the tags:)

Comment: This does not work for TypeScript. `@example` answer works well.

Answer (score 82):

`@example` http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wiki/TagExample

```
/**
 * This function does something see example below:
 * @example
 * var x = foo("test"); //it will show "test" message
 *
 * @param {string} str: string argument that will be shown in message
 */
function foo(str)
{
   alert(str);
}
```

Comment: from the docs you linked : The @example tag is not intended to be used to generate "inline" examples, if you want this, you need to do it via HTML markup embedded within a @description block, using the <code> tag, for example.

Comment: gjslint which enforces the Google JavaScript StyleGuide doesn't allow @example tags...so you might want to use the <pre><code></code></pre> solution.

Comment: This is also a method supported by VS Code's Intellisense. https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/30062

Comment: VS Code (at time of writing) doesn't seem to support HTML tags though. :(  I tried `<pre>` and `<code>` and they were just written literally in the Intellisense. However, I just realized that Markdown seems to be supported!!! So surrounding inline code with backticks (`) works. :)

Answer (score 44):

Jsdoc3 has a markdown plugin but it is turned off by default. Enable it the default config file `./node_modules/jsdoc/conf.json.EXAMPLE` via ...

```
"plugins": [
    "plugins/markdown"
],
```

... and you have nice syntax support for docs, including for code.  Markdown uses three backticks (```` ``` ````) to demarcate code blocks. For to use the original example:

````
/**
* This function does something see example below:
* ```
* var x = foo("test"); //it will show "test" message
* ```
* @param {string} str: string argument that will be shown in message
*/
````

Comment: I have enabled markdown plugin via `conf.json`- is there a way to display inline code, ie that which is usually achieved with single back ticks `like this`?  Edit: 
 actually it does work, it's just the style of the code tags are pretty minimal by default.

Comment: In Visual Studio Code, Markdown support seems to be available out-of-the-box

Answer (score 6):

You can put any HTML in JSDoc and it will be copied out. Heres an example of what I use:

```
/** 
 * The ReplaceSlang method replaces the string &quot;hi&quot; with &quot;hello&quot;.
 *   <script language="javascript">
 *     function testFunc() {
 *       alert(ReplaceSlang(prompt("Enter sample argument")));
 *     }
 *   </script>
 *   <input type="button" value="Test" onclick="testFunc()" />
 * @param {String} str The text to transform
 * @return {String}
 */
exports.ReplaceSlang = function(str) {
  return str.replace("hi", "hello");
};
```

To make sure the button is not in the summary, add a sentence and a dot (.) before it.

You need to find some way to include your javascript file in the output of JSDoc so that they are loaded. (Your code otherwise does not exist as javascript in the output of JSDoc – you can modify the template for that : see [JsPlate documentation](http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wiki/JsPlate))

Comment: I am sorry, I just realised that is not what you wanted to do. Do you mind if I leave this comment in case it helps someone ?

Answer (score 6):

Using [@example](https://jsdoc.app/tags-example.html) works for most cases, but HTML reserved characters need to be translated to HTML entities: `&lt;` `&gt;` and so on, otherwise the HTML will be rendered and not displayed as code.

From the linked documentation:

```js
/**
 * Solves equations of the form a * x = b
 * @example
 * // returns 2
 * globalNS.method1(5, 10);
 * @example
 * // returns 3
 * globalNS.method(5, 15);
 * @returns {Number} Returns the value of x for the equation.
 */
globalNS.method1 = function (a, b) {
    return b / a;
};
```

An example with a caption:

```js
/**
 * Solves equations of the form a * x = b
 * @example <caption>Example usage of method1.</caption>
 * // returns 2
 * globalNS.method1(5, 10);
 * @returns {Number} Returns the value of x for the equation.
 */
globalNS.method1 = function (a, b) {
    return b / a;
};
```

Answer (score 5):

For [jsdoc3](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc) `<code>...</code>` seems to work just fine. It also keeps the code inline while adding in `<pre>` creates a paragraph (which is what it should do anyways). [Browser support](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_code.asp) seems to be ok so I don't see any reason to not use it.